# How to handle buttons with same value but different names in Spring

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a table that is dynamically created that has rows of movies.
It has a title column,
a media type column,
a rating column,
and a column that contains a "view" button.
When one of these view buttons is clicked,
I would like to go to a page that contains all the details of that movie by sending the title to the controller so I can query for it in mySql.
The problem is that for all these buttons,
the value is always going to be "view".
So my solution is to make the name of the button different as shown in the code below (this is the raw html generated from the jsp):

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="someAction">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>type</th>
                <th>rating</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>title1</td>
                <td>DVD</td>
                <td>R</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="mediaType.title1" value="view"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>title2</td>
                <td>DVD</td>
                <td>R</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="mediaType.title2" value="view"></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>title3</td>
                <td>BLU-RAY</td>
                <td>PG-13</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="mediaType.title3" value="view"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I could then use a parameterMap to figure out which view was pressed.
That is messy and Spring has to have some way of being able to do this.
I thought something like this would work in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("someAction", params = "mediaType.{title}=view")
public ModelAndView loadPage(String title) {
    // use title to query mysql
    // build Model
    // return ModelAndView
}
```

However this doesn't work.
Is there something that I can use in Spring that would be simpler and cleaner like above instead of getting the parameterMap from the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you have rows of information organized into a table.  You're looping through some kind of collection, which has the side effect of making each input field have similar 'name' attributes.  As a result, it's difficult to determine which input fields you really care about. You've then chosen to use the button as an identifier (presumably, because only the one button you actually click on get's added to the request -all the others don't get submitted) to determine which 'row', and subsequent input fields.

**I think this might all come down to which 'button' you're using**.  If you're using a literal input tag (type="submit" or "button") the 'value' attribute is what the user sees as the text on the button -so, you're forced to play shenanigans with the 'name' attribute (presumably by adding an index to the name, splitting the string once you get it out of the request, and using that identifier to get the other parameters out of the request that also have the same identifier appended to their 'name' attribute).

JSP

```
<input type="submit" name="view${varStatus.index}" value="View" />
```

HTML Source

```
<input type="submit" name="view3" value="View">
```

You should probably **use the button tag** instead. It allows the text that the user sees to be different than the value that is submitted in the request.

JSP

```
<button type="submit" name="view" value="${varStatus.index}" >View</button>
```

HTML Source

```
<button type="submit" name="view" value="3">View</button>
```

This gives you the 'identifier' for the row.

**How Spring fits into this:**
I played with the @RequestMapping and the @RequestParam annotations, and was unable to get Spring to give me the values directly into the controller.  But, I was able to do it by writing a custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver along with a custom annotation.

*note: I'm using annotations and java config instead of xml config, AND probably more importantly -this was a quick and dirty example to get it working.  adjust it as needed for your situation.*

**HandlerMethodArgumentResolver**

[image: DynamicRequestParamArgumentResolver]

**Annotation**

[image: DynamicRequestParam]

**Controller method**

[image: Controller method]

Comment: the annotation probably doesn't need to be annotated with the @Component (copy and paste error).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the table inside one form, you could put multiple forms inside the table, in the TRs:

```
<tr>
  <form action="someAction">
  <td>title1<input type='hidden' name='title' value='title1' /></td>
  <td>DVD</td>
  <td>R</td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="view"></td>
  </form>
</tr>
```

Then each title has its own form and you send in the title (always with parameter name of `title`) from a hidden input.

Comment: I have thought of these two answers however that's not what I'm looking for.  There has to be some way that spring can dynamically figure out parameter names.  Spring can figure out dynamic mapping by this:

    @RequestMapping(value = "{transactionId}/continue", params = "submitButton=Continue")
    public ModelAndView continueByButton(String transactionId)

Comment: Spring does have something like this for PathVariables, to turn parts of the URL into params, but trying to regex actual parameter names like this is probably not in demand enough for them to have done anything for that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in this statement:
"I have a table that is dynamically created that has rows of movies".

Presumably,
you are looping through a list of movies and generating the table in the jsp file and each row has some unique identifier.
Add a hidden to identify the selected row.
Set the value of the hidden value in an onclick handler from the submit buttons.
Here is some example stuff:

```
<form ...>
<c:forEach blah var="row">
    <tr>
      ...
        <td><input type="submit" value="View" onclick="setSelectedRow('${row.id}')"/></td>
</c:forEach>
<input type="hidden" id="blammy" name="blammy" value=""/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setSelectedRow(rowId)
    {
        ... set blammy.value equal to rowId.
    }
</script>

// the id is used by JavaScript to find the object in the DOM.
// the name is what appears in the request.

@RequestMapping("someAction")
public ModelAndView loadPage(
    @RequestParameter("blammy") final String blammy)
{
    ...
}
```